# 0x00 в char (c++)

Tags: hex, c++

```
char mychar[BUF_SIZE] = {0x12, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x08, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x13, 0x06, 0x88, 0x10, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0x02, 0x0a};

for (i=0;i<(strlen(mychar;i++){ 
    sprintf(str,"%s %02x", str, mychar[i]); 
}
```

Получаю "12 68 11 01 08 68 11 01".

0x00 - считается признаком конца массива символов. А как получить остальное?

Comment: Может так?

   #include <stdio.h>
   int main() {
     char mychar[] = {0x12, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x08, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x13, 0x06, 0x88, 0x10, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0x02, 0x0a};
     {
       char    str[sizeof mychar/sizeof(char) * 3];
       int     i, n = 0;
       for(i = 0; i < sizeof mychar/sizeof(char);) {
         n += sprintf(str+n, "%02x",   (unsigned char) mychar[i++]);
         str[n++] = ' ';
       }
       str[n ? --n : 0] = '\0';
       printf("%s\n", str);
     }
     return 0;
   }

Comment: @alexlz, ненавижу захардкоженные магические константы для работы со строками :-)

Comment: @gecube, "магическая константа" - это **трешка**?

Comment: @gecube, подозреваю. что они отвечают Вам взаимностью. Ну в сишной библиотеке ещё и realloc есть.

Чего-то вспомнилось. А уж как негры, на которых посыпалась "Ариан-5" ненавидят захардкоженные магические константы. Касающиеся параметров двигателей ракеты.

Comment: @alexlz, ну, в с++ я стараюсь чаще оперировать std::string для работы со строками, хотя как и контейнер его тоже можно использовать. А касательно трешки - завтра взбрендит перевести программу на юникод или добавить символ разделителя и прога сломается...

Comment: Низкоуровневая работа с char на C и юникод -- бррр. Даже не пытался представить sprintf с юникодом. А если sprintf работает, то malloc/realloc.

Кстати, у ТС в вопросе результат неправильный -- там впереди пробел должен быть (перед 12). И у меня (без юникода), если пробел заносить, изменив шаблон на "%02x ", вместо `(str[n++]=0;`) то размер str надо будет увеличить на единицу.

Comment: IMHO у ТС пробел перед хексом просто потому, что более нормального алгоритма он придумать не смог. 

Стоит ли повторять такое?

А юникод здесь вообще ни при чем. Написано же `char`, не надо все же извращаться, считайте (почти всегда), что `char` это 1 байт из 8 бит.

Comment: Юникод на С? wchar_t и никаких проблем. На никсах, во всяком случае.

Comment: Ну если wchar_t -- это "никаких проблем"...

Unicode никак не будет таким же простым, как char (для en_US).

Comment: А где тут Си? В тегах ясно написано С++

Comment: @gecube, если программа компилируется С++ компилятором, то она является С++ программой?

Comment: @avp, в определенном смысле - да. К тому же далеко не любая программа Си будет компилироваться без ошибок или корректно работать после попытки компиляции компилятором С++

Comment: @gecube, то что *не любая* - это хорошо известно. Я, если честно, не понял некого противопоставления С и С++ в Вашем комментарии. 

IMHO, если речь идет о базовых типах и массивах, то языки практически одинаковы. С глобальными константами, правда, совсем не так, но к данному типу задач это не относится.

Comment: А где здесь вещи, которые не будут скомпилированы С++ компилятором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
#undef LOCAL_MOD_BUFF_SIZE
#define LOCAL_MOD_BUFF_SIZE 1024

    char str[LOCAL_MOD_BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    char mychar[] = {
        0x12, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x08, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x13, 0x06, 0x88, 0x10, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x02,
        0x00, 0x03, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0x02, 0x0a
    };
    for (int i=0, len = 0; i < sizeof(mychar); i++, len = strlen(str)){ 
        sprintf_s(&str[len], LOCAL_MOD_BUFF_SIZE - len - 1, "%02x ", (unsigned char)mychar[i]);
    }
    printf(str);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Ключевой момент был в "(unsigned char)mychar[i]", помогло.

Comment: @vv2cc, перевычисление длины (когда Вы сами увеличиваете ее на 3) на каждом шаге это какая-то глубокая задумка?

Comment: @avp, ага. мало-ли поменяли шаблон(например убрали пробел) и потом непонятно почему странный вывод идет. причем шаблон может быть измен динамически. защита от невнимательности.

Comment: То-то я вижу, что несмотря на постоянный рост гигабайт и гигагерц программы быстрее не работают.

Answer (score 4):

> 0x00 - считается признаком конца
> массива символов

Нет, 0 - признак конца строки. Массив символов - это массив символов, независимо от их значений :) Ergo, его длина узнаётся как и для других массивов, в данном случае - sizeof().

P.S. strlen() в for, while, do etc - забыть раз и навсегда :)

Comment: Спасибо за теорию, полезно.

Comment: А вот это правило откуда?

    strlen() в for, while, do etc - забыть раз и навсегда :)

Или это просто очередной совет "пользоваться strnlen"?

Comment: Если вам хочется вычислять длину строки при каждой итерации - на здоровье :-) (или кому-то непонятно, что это относится к strlen, а не к обсуждаемому примеру с массивом?)

Comment: Если строка не меняется, то меня это волновать не должно. На это умные люди есть, они компиляторы пишут. А если меняется -- так иногда не лишне и проверить.

Comment: По мне так лучше сначала выработать привычку выносить инварианты за цикл, чем не :-) А потом уже расслабляться, если захочется.

Comment: @klopp А лучше пользоваться языками без операторов цикла.

Answer (score 3):

Что же так компьютер мучить?  Вывод в шестнадцатиричном формате - это очень просто.

```
// (hex dump) вывод блока памяти в строку через пробел
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char mychar[] = {0x12, 0x68, 0x11, 0x01, 0x08, 0x68, 0x11, 
         0x01, 0x00, 0x13, 0x06, 0x88, 0x10, 0x0b, 
         0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0x02, 0x0a};

char *
hexdumpstr (const char *src, size_t size)
{
  static const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
  char *result = (char *)malloc((size > 0)? size*3: 1),
    *p = result;

  if (result) {
    while (size-- > 0) {
      *p++ = hex[(*src >> 4) & 0x0f];
      *p++ = hex[*src++ & 0x0f];
      *p++ = ' ';
    }
    p[(p > result)? -1: 0] = 0;
  }

  return result;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *hexdump = hexdumpstr(mychar,sizeof(mychar));

  printf ("str hex: [%s]\n",hexdump? hexdump: "Out of memory");
  if (hexdump)
    free(hexdump);

  exit (0);
}
```

Никакие `sprintf` и постоянное перевычисление длины результата (`strlen`) тут абсолютно не нужны.

Comment: Вот за что одно можно любить чистый С, так это за постоянную тренировку мозга.

Comment: Программирование на C++ чревато атрофией мозга? Жесть!

Comment: ну если С++грозит короткий мозга, то что говорить о каком-нибудь РНР

Answer (score 3):

Немного не в тему, но вот как это можно сделать на "нормальном" С++:

```
ostringstream s("");
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(mychar)/sizeof (mychar[0]); i++) {
   s << "0x" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (int) (unsigned char) mychar[i] << " ";   
}   
cout << s.str() << endl;
```

Comment: `(int) (unsigned char)` -- круто. А как же будет на "ненормальном" C++?

Comment: См. предыдущие ответы.

Comment: А, я понял. 

    static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(mychar[i]))

Comment: Тоже годится. Совершенство не знает предела.

Answer (score 2):

М, сложные какие-то ответы.
Нужно изменить одну строку.

```
 for (i=0;i<sizeof(mychar);i++){
```

Comment: И получить попадос, если sizeof(mychar[0]) не равен 1

Comment: А вот вероятность такого события очень невелика. Разве что на каком-то экзотическом микроконтроллере, но вероятность такой экзотики сильно снижает присутствие sprintf

Comment: А вдруг кто-то захочет эту программу портировать на этот самый микроконтроллер. А тут такая свинья лежит...

Comment: Учитывая, что найти не-байтную организацию RAM весьма сложно (я про такие не слышал, архитектура pdp8 -- не всчёт), а уж компилятор Си для такой мелкосхемы -- тем более, то вариант с небайтной организацией -- флеш/ROM на чём-нибудь типа Microchip'овских PIC'ов с их собственной длиной слова программной памяти. И морока по организации/использованию данных там будет достаточной, чтобы об этой конкретной свинье не беспокоиться.

В случае avr8 с 16-ти разрядными словами флеша таких проблем вроде возникать не должно, там (если не путаю) компилятор производит отображение байт на эти слова.

Comment: Если учитывать все экзотические ситуации можно сойти с ума. Ненужное усложнение.

Comment: Вот подложите вы человеку свинью, вот вам икаться будет.

Comment: Свинья: усложнять все. Потолще будет. )

Comment: Узко Вы смотрите на вещи, молодой человек. Пошире надо, пошире. Потолще.

Comment: Правильно. Чем толще свинья, тем больше мяса и САЛА!!!

Comment: Абсолютно согласен. Вы на правильном пути, молодой человек.