# Как из char str[] = "70bf" получить char newstr[] = { 0x70, 0xbf } ?

Tags: hex, c++, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Как из `char str[] = "70bf"` получить `char newstr[] = { 0x70, 0xbf }`?
В какую сторону смотреть?

C++, linux

Comment: Дело в том, что char принимает значение от -129 до 128, т.е. -81 до 80 в шестнадцатеричной системе. Лучше используйте unsigned char

Comment: Да, конечно, это просто для примера в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) с ключом %X или [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) с нужным radix'ом. Символы, если сложно разобрать саму строчку, можно выдирать по два. И ваааааще - почему используете массивы char'ов? В школе не говорили, что лучше использовать `std::string`? А тогда можно использовать [`stringstream` с операцией `>>` и модификатором `hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Решение немного в стиле [@avp](/users/232/avp)

```
#include  <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

inline int _hexchar(char a) {
    if ((a <= '9') and (a >= '0'))  return a -'0';  
    if ((a <= 'f') and (a >= 'a')) return a - 'a' + 10;
    if ((a <= 'F') and (a >= 'A')) return a - 'A' + 10;
    throw (invalid_argument ("Not a hex string"));
}

unsigned char hex_to_uchar (const char* str) {
    return _hexchar(str[0])*16 + _hexchar(str[1]);
}

int main () {
    unsigned char buf[2];
    char str [] = "70bf";
    buf[0] = hex_to_uchar (str);
    buf [1] = hex_to_uchar (str + 2);   
    cout << hex << showbase << (int) buf[0] << "  " << (int) buf [1] << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@mikillskegg немного опередил, и у него красивей, но все же приведу свое (Си, g++ транслируется тоже).

Хотел сказать, что задачка просто обратная [вчерашней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/156435) от того же автора. Поэтому результат проверяется уже готовой (вчерашней программкой).

Если вчера была задача сделать дамп памяти, то сегодня - заполнить память сделанным (наверное вчера) дампом (уже слегка упакованным).

```
// строка hex в память
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
  xstr() "распаковывает" строку шестнадцатиричных вида 01ab0f00d0...
  (по 2 hex без пробелов и т.п.) 
  в область памяти максимальной длины size
  Завершается по концу строки или первой не hex
  Возвращает количество помещенных в память байт 
    при завершении по концу строки - больше нуля
    при завершении по не hex - меньше нуля
 */

static inline int
tohex (int *c)
{
  if (*c >= '0' && *c <= '9')
    *c -= '0';
  else if (*c >= 'a' && *c <= 'f')
    *c = *c - 'a' + 10;
  else
    return 0;
  return 1;
}

static inline int
puthex(char *str, char *mem)
{
  int c1 = tolower((unsigned char)str[0]), 
    c2 = tolower((unsigned char)str[1]),
    rc = tohex(&c1) && tohex(&c2);

  if (rc) 
    *mem = (c1<<4)|c2;
  return rc;
}

int
xstr (char *str, char *mem, size_t size)
{
  int l = 0;

  while (l < size && *str) {
    if (!puthex(str,mem++))
      return -l;
    str += 2;
    l++;
  }
  return l;
}

#define abs(x) ((x)<0? -(x):(x))
extern char *hexdumpstr (const char *, size_t);

main ()
{
  char src[]="01090aa100fFEfяя", dst[100];

  int l = xstr(src,dst,100);
  char *res = hexdumpstr(dst,abs(l));

  printf ("l = %d (%d) res = [%s]\n",l,abs(l),res);
  if (res)
    free(res);

  exit (0);
}
```

Вот компилим и печатаем

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ xstr.c xtostr.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
l = -7 (7) res = [01 09 0a a1 00 ff ef]
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: Ух, ты, молодцы какие! Целые простынки кода написали. Реально супер! +1

Comment: Присоединяйся.

Comment: Похоже профессионализма авторам пока не хватает. Ср. с образцом (http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html)

Comment: @alexlz, ваша ссылка - битая.

Comment: @vladimir_ki Странно. У меня открывается. А вообще -- гугл, "Эволюция программиста".

Comment: @alexlz, хотите сказать до "Master Programmer" не дотягиваем? 

И хорошо, мне больше нравится "Experienced Hacker".

Answer (score 1):

Я использую это:

```
bool CUtil::Hex2Buf(const std::string &Hex, uint8_t **OutBuf, ::size_t &OutSize)
{
    bool Res = false;
    if(*OutBuf == NULL)
    {
        OutSize = Hex.size() / 2;
        uint8_t *out = new uint8_t[OutSize];
        if(out != NULL)
        {
            memset(out, 0, sizeof(uint8_t) * OutSize);

            for(size_t i = 0; i < OutSize; i++)
            {
                char buf[3] = {Hex[(i * 2)], Hex[(i * 2) + 1], 0};
                char *p;
                out[i] = (uint8_t)strtoul(buf, &p, 16);

            }
            *OutBuf = out;
            Res = true;
        }
    }
    return Res;
}
bool CUtil::Buf2Hex(std::string &Out, const uint8_t *InBuf, const ::size_t InSize)
{
    bool Res = false;
    if(InBuf != NULL && InSize != 0)
    {
        Out.clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < InSize; ++i)
        {
            char Buff[10] = {0};
            sprintf(Buff, "%02X", InBuf[i]);
            Out += Buff;
        }
        Res = true;
    }
    return Res;
}
```

если нужны коментарии - обращайтесь :)

Comment: Самописная библиотека?

Comment: @sterh, пара вопросов:

1. Зачем обнулять память, которая будет заполняться?

2. Почему не проверяете удалось ли strtoul() правильно преобразовать код? И, при ошибке, возможно логичнее вернуть false?

Comment: @gecube
да
@avp
1) просто инициализация переменной - очень помогает при отладке
2) конкретно здесь - это очень простой случай, и шанс ошибки очень мал. Вы конечно правы, нужно проверить возвращаемое значение

Answer (score 1):

Сначала преобразовать в unsigned int (пусть это будет x), затем использовать поразрядную операцию & (1 ампересанд)с масками x & 0xFF00 >> 8 - старший байт
                                   x & 0x00FF      - младший бай